# Querying over row (composite) values with EF Core and Npgsql

Tags: postgresql, npgsql, ef-core-2.0

I'm trying to query PostgreSQL with so-called row values with the following SQL syntax: `WHERE (field1, field1) < (value1, value2)` (which is different from `WHERE field1 < value1 AND field2 < value2`) and was wondering if the Npgsql provider for EF Core would produce such query in any way (haven't found anything in the [online doc](http://www.npgsql.org/efcore/index.html))

Thanks in advance.

**EDIT**

To clarify my intent, I would like to implement keyset pagination as described in slide 22 of [this page](https://use-the-index-luke.com/blog/2013-07/pagination-done-the-postgresql-way) (full video [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GzMaN-IX7wQ)). Basically, the idea is that if you paginate a query that's ordered by `f` descending for example, you would actually do a `ORDER BY f desc, id desc`; then in order to fetch the next page, you add `WHERE (f, id) < (prev_f, prev_id)`.

Comment: The first question is how you would represent such construct in LINQ query. Then you can check how it is translated to SQL.

Comment: Still not clear how `WHERE (f, id)  < (prev_f, prev_id)` is different from `WHERE f < prev_f AND id < prev_id`, can you please explain?

Comment: From the slides about pagination that I've quoted, `WHERE (f, id) < (prev_f, prev_id)` is true if and only if `f < prev_f or (f = prev_f and id < prev_id)`. Seems to be a feature that few DBs implement (although it's in the SQL standard) and Postgres is one of them, but I've to admit that I haven't found any mention of it in the Postgres documentation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Composite types aren't yet supported in the Npgsql EF Core provider: [this issue tracks that](https://github.com/npgsql/Npgsql.EntityFrameworkCore.PostgreSQL/issues/22).

But regardless, as @ivan-stoev wrote, C# doesn't support comparing tuples in the way that you describe. Can you explain exactly what you're looking for? What would `(f1,f2) < (v1,v2)` mean exactly?

Comment: I've edited my question to clarify what I'm trying to achieve. I'm not sure it's related to Postgres' composite types, it's more of a way to declare a `WHERE` statement with multiple clauses.

Comment: So once again, EF Core is an O/RM which translates C# expressions to SQL counterparts. Since tuple comparison (`(f1,f2) , (v1,v2)`) doesn't exist in C# syntax AFAIK, this cannot be done. On the other hand this really adds zero value over `f1 < v1 && f2 < v2`.

Comment: Totally got your point about the syntax not mapping to C#. As for "adding zero value", this construct does not correspond to a `f1 < v1 && f2 < v2` comparison and as far as I understand, that's why it was added to the SQL standard, but that's beyond my initial question. Thanks a lot for your time and your excellent support!